# Пояснить за различные библиотеки для работы с Identity

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Прошу объяснить, пояснить, рассказать про разницу между различными библиотеками для работы с Identity. Что сейчас используют, для чего подходят, что платно, что бесплатно? Хотелось бы получить развёрнутый ответ. Буду очень благодарен!

Слышал про Openiddict, OpenID Connect, Identity server. Вроде бы что-то ещё было. Но в голове сейчас каша из этого всего.

Comment: Дополните вопрос деталями: для чего именно вам нужна такая библитека, какие именно требования к ней?

Comment: @aepot на текущий момент, к сожалению, нет требований, поэтому вопрос звучит размыто. Ввиду этого, я бы хотел получить развёрнутый ответ, который стал бы моей отправной точкой для дальнейшего изучения и понимания

Comment: В таком формате на него либо сложно, либо невозможно дать объективный ответ.

Comment: Вероятно, вы правы. Но я подумал, что вводный ответ из разряда (Openiddict - это такая опен сорс билиотека, которая позволяет делать это, это и это, она не сильно популярна, потому то) будет вполне достаточным и не сложным для того, кто часто с ними взаимодействовал или как-то изучал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Openiddict - opensource библиотека, которая предоставляет универсальное решение для реализации сервера OpenID Connect* и проверки токенов в любом ASP.NET приложении. Поддерживает работу с Entity Framework

*OpenID Connect - уровень идентификации поверх протокола OAuth 2.0, т.е. если простым языком, то он позволяет установить личность находящегося человека на сайте, в том числе и REST-подобным образом. Если ещё проще - аналог куки.

P.S. очень рекомендую к прочтению статью на хабре по этому поводу: https://habr.com/ru/post/281406/

Она даёт первое и общее впечатление об OpenID Connect. Мне на старте она пригодилась :)

Comment: Сейчас нашел на stackexchange ответ на вопрос, когда использовать OpenID, а когда OpenID Connect: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44797/when-do-you-use-openid-vs-openid-connect тоже может помочь :)